# How to call ASP.NET MVC Web API from React Native Mobile App using localhost

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net-mvc, react-native, asp.net-web-api

I built WEB Api with ASP.NET MVC. I can access the API with fetch from JavaScript in my browser. But when I try to access the API from React Native App, I get a warning: "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):......."

I do understand the warning since nothing is showing up on the screen, but I do wonder how would anyone call Web api on localhost from react native app.

I am running my react native app with "expo start --localhost --android" and it is showing up on my android phone connected with USB to my mashine.

**App.Js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from "react-native";

import Constants from "expo-constants";

import Row from "./Row";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: null,
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch("https://localhost:44343/api/movies")
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          movies: data,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ movies: [...this.state.movies, err] });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>-MOVIES-</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.movies}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Row movies={item} />}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 40
  }
});
```

if you look at `componentDidMount()` i tried to call `fetch("https://localhost:44343/api/movies")`, but it is not working, but when i run my app on Web, it is working just fine.

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this, so I can call api directly from react native?

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

-> When you use your localhost base URL in your fetch request, it refers to the local machine where the react native development server is running, not the machine where your API is hosted.

-> In your case, replace `localhost(https://localhost:44343)` with the actual IP address of your machine, You can't use localhost because it refers to the device itself.

-> You can find your machine IP address by running `ipconfig` (for Windows user) and check your API is configured to accept requests from the network.

-> modify your code (Javascript) ... something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  return fetch("http://<YOUR_MACHINE_IP>:44343/api/movies")
    // Replace<YOUR_MACHINE_IP> with your machine's IP address
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        movies: data,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.setState({ movies: [...this.state.movies, err] });
    });
}
```